# Kafka consumers - 1 common topic / n different consumers, but each one only its data. Possible?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I'm new to Kafka and I have a question about consumers I'm quite puzzled...

If I have a topic where is being registered all data, but then, there are multiple consumers interested only on data refered to itself. Something like this:


`Common Topic:                      Consumer 1             Consumer 2
JSONForConsumer1                     Mine!!!                Idle
JSONForConsumer2                     Idle                   Mine!!!
JSONForConsumer3                     Idle                   Idle
JSONForConsumer1                     Mine!!!                Idle
...`

Now, what I have (but I would like to remove if possible) is:

`Common Topic:                      Consumer 1             Consumer 2
JSONForConsumer1                  Is it mine? Yes!!!      Is it mine? No...
JSONForConsumer2                  Is it mine? No...       Is it mine? Yes!!!
JSONForConsumer3                  Is it mine? No...       Is it mine? No...
JSONForConsumer1                  Is it mine? Yes!!!      Is it mine? No...
...`

So, is it possible, (without creating topics for each consumer) that each consumer only process data refered to itself?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Not really. The best you can do is have a partitioned topic and each consumer only has to look at the partition that contains what it needs. However, that required that such a partitioning scheme exists for your application (you must map messages and consumers to keys somehow). Or just multiple topics if there is really no overlap.

Comment: Thank you Thilo! For the sake of simplicity, I will keep the current implementation.But I'm curious about performance loss (or gain) of the topic per consumer combination. I'll give it a try.